# XML to database and vice-versa

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I can insert my XML easily into my database table, but i follow this exhausting manner as seen in my down code using LINK, which is perfectly tested. But, I wonder if I can find a way to read all my XML descendants elements of "Level" node, using iteration of all child tagnames, because when I make any change to my XML file, I would have to change my LINK code once again,and usually i'll face some errors when i use this exhausting manner. Please help improve this code:

```
try
{
    XElement d = XElement.Parse(richTextBox1.Text.ToString());

        var people = (from Level in d.Descendants("Level")
                      select new
                      {
                          ID = Convert.ToInt32(Level.Element("ID").Value),
                          Day1 = Level.Element("Day1").Value,
                          Day2 = Level.Element("Day2").Value,
                          Day3 = Level.Element("Day3").Value,
                          Day4 = Level.Element("Day4").Value,
                          Day5 = Level.Element("Day5").Value,
                          Day6 = Level.Element("Day6").Value,
                          Day7 = Level.Element("Day7").Value
                      }).ToList();
        foreach (var item in people)
        {
            //Insert and Update                    
            datacommand1.CommandText = "Insert Into MyTable(ID,Day1,Day2,Day3,Day4,Day5,Day6,Day7) values(" + item.ID + ","  + "','" + item.Day1 + "','" + item.Day2 + "','" + item.Day3 + "','" + item.Day4 + "','" + item.Day5 + "','" + item.Day6 + "','" + item.Day7 + "')";
            datacommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
        }                    
}
```

my XML file seems like that:

```
<level>
    <id> 101 </id>
    <Day1> task 1</Day1>
    <Day2> task 2</Day2>
    <Day3> task 3</Day3>
    <Day4> task 4</Day4>
    <Day5> task 5</Day5>
    <Day6> task 6</Day6>
    <Day7> task7 </Day7>

</level>
```

Comment: It seems that the problem may go well beyond the code, since, judging by the `INSERT` instruction submitted to DB, the table where it's stored is also hardcoded according to your current XML structure. If that ever changes, you would have to change BOTH the code AND the DB. Maybe you can think in using a single field in DB to contain the whole document, without needing the parse at all. Also, and unrelated to the question, be aware of SQL injection.

Comment: well, it's still easy for me to change the sql code accordingly, but i just want to iterate the tagnames of Level node in this example and get their values

Comment: @Alejandro thank you very much indeed, that's exactly what i'm seeking. But, i'm still wondering that my database table contains both of integer and string fields, with my expected further modifications, how to overcome this problem in your EXCELLENT code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declaring one variable for each tag in the file, you may want to try to iterate over all them, extracting the name and the value for each one and composing the SQL statement at runtime from those, no matter what they are. Try something like this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> items = d.Descendants("level").Elements();
string names = string.Empty;
string values = string.Empty;
foreach (XElement item in items)
{
    names += item.Name + ",";
    values += "@" + item.Name + ",";
    IDbDataParameter parameter = datacommand1.CreateParameter();
    parameter.ParameterName = "@" + item.Name;
    parameter.DbType = DbType.String;
    parameter.Value = item.Value;
    datacommand1.Parameters.Add(parameter);
}
datacommand1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable (" + names.Substring(names.Length - 1) + ") VALUES (" + values.Substring(values.Length - 1) + ");";
datacommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This builds the command on the fly, based on the XML structure, and fills its parameters with the data there. But doing so relies on the fact that the table structure will be exactly the same as in the file, and still needs manual schema updating when the structure changes, but as long as they're in sync it should be fine.

**EDIT**

About datatypes, there are 2 choices I can think of. Leave as it is, sending everything as strings no matter what, and rely on the DB engine to parse, validate and turn those into numbers (depending on what DB you're using, that may be possible or not, but I guess it's not rare to see). Or modify the code to separate the special fields apart from the loop (and excluding from it) and add those one by one, specifying their types accordingly. This is easy to do if the numeric columns are fixed, like the ID, and everything else is text.

Comment: well, that's great! but, though i try to test your code, while making even all my database table fields of text type (not integer), i still face the message:(An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.)

Comment: OK, seems like the SQL statement is not properly constructed (that's what happens when you don't test before posting :D). Try single stepping when it builds the command to see where it has an error, most likely it would be a comma or a wrong parameter.

Comment: i completely understand the whole idea now; but, i'll be very grateful if you can detect where the error exactly, i just can find it's in the sql statement, but not able to detect it, please help

Comment: Well, I could fix this problem manually by some addition; BUT, the real problem that your code supposes that I have only one "Level" node in my XML and accordingly just also one record in my database table. i already have several "Level" nodes that should insert several records in database table while the sql parameter inserts just only one record, do you have a solution?